# Mute sound of Media Player using java

Tags: java

Can we control the sound of a vlc player,windows media player etc. using java.I do google whole day but can not find find anything useful.
I am trying various things but can't find anything which do my work can anyone.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.BooleanControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;

public class Sound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Mixer.Info[] infos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        for (Mixer.Info info: infos) {
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);


        Line[] line=mixer.getSourceLines();
        BooleanControl bc = (BooleanControl) line.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
                if (bc != null) {
                    bc.setValue(true); // true to mute the line, false to unmute

}
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: From a security standpoint, I would be very concerned if that were possible.

Comment: Can you suggest me another way  to mute the sound of any media player.